# How to select a file from android memory to do some action on it

Tags: android, file, file-upload

I want to transfer a file into android dev's SD memory and read the file for parsing it.
But i don't know how to transfer a file into the emulators SD Card.

Also I don't know which api is to be used to browse for the file from the application.
This app provides the user to show it where he has kept the file which the app has to parse.
Which api does android provide for file management using a UI.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps to push the file into Adroid Emulator SDcard in eclipse.**

> 1. Click on the DDMS tab on the right top corner of the eclipse IDE
> 2. Go to File Explore in it, if not there the Windows->Show View->File
>      Explorer
> 3. Click on the SDCard in the file explorer
> 4. On the top of the File Explorer there are 2 Arrows(Right direction and
>      Left Direction)
>      To put the file into the SD card press the right direction arrow,
>      browse the location
>      where the file is located click Ok, To pull the file back from the
>      SDcard click on the
>      file to be pulled the click on the left direction arrow

**Shell commands to push and pull files from/to SDcard**

> device commands:
>
> > ```
> > adb push <local> <remote>    - copy file/dir to device
> >
> > adb pull <remote> <local>    - copy file/dir from device
> > ```
> >
> > Push sends a file from your desktop
> >     computer to your Android device:
> >
> > adb push test.txt /sdcard/test.txt
> >
> > Pull pulls a file from your Android
> >     device to your desktop computer:
> >
> > adb pull /sdcard/test.txt test.txt
>
> To read the file programatically you
>   use
>
> > **import java.io.File**
> >
> > File lObjFile = new
> >     File("sdcard/fileName.ext");

Comment: Vinayak Thanks for the help... but about files this code helps to get a file whose path is know while the prog is written. But here i want to give user the option to select his file from a the devices memory...? what can i do here...?

Comment: Have a look at this for the file browser

http://www.anddev.org/building_an_android_filebrowser_list-based_-t67.html

Comment: Sad android don't have one in build like it has Intent to contacts